# Need to select sum of the same field in SQL with diffrent Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables used to select sum of the same field with different conditions now tried the query is follows But result showing same in the two fields

```
SELECT  sum( s.message_count) as total,(case when s.dlr_status = 'DELIVRD' then sum( s.message_count) end ) as delivered  
FROM `sent` s join `track` t on t.track_id = s.track_id  group by t.sent_type
```

Any help would be appreciable
 Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `sum` outside of the `case..when` projection, and for completeness, return zero in the 'else'. You'll also need the `sent_type` column in the select in order to group by it.

```
SELECT  
    t.sent_type,
    sum(s.message_count) as total,
    sum(case when s.dlr_status = 'DELIVRD' then s.message_count else 0 end) as delivered  
FROM `sent` s join `track` t on t.track_id = s.track_id  
group by t.sent_type;
```